# Exclude rows with null values

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, row-value-expression

I'm doing a bunch of sum queries:

```
SELECT col1 + col2 + col3 + ...
```

Some of the values in some of the columns are `null`. I'm checking for them by doing:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1 is not null and col2 is not null and ...
```

I wonder if there is a more concise syntax for accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, since [the sum of any number and `null` is `null`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Mathematical_and_string_concatenation), you can do something like the following (with the obvious `...` filled in):

```
select big_honking_sum
from(
    select col1+col2+col3+...+coln as big_honking_sum
    from some_table
)sum
where big_honking_sum is not null;
```

Comment: Ohh, thanks.  I had it in my head that 1 + null equaled 1.  I guess I've been programming too much javascript.

Comment: @canisrufus - You're most welcome.  If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark below the upvote/downvote arrows next to my answer.

Comment: ;) SO won't let me select an answer for the first fifteen minutes.

Answer (score 6):

Use COALESCE function if you can accept that a NULL value will be treated as 0.

```
SELECT COALESCE(Col1,0)
      + COALESCE(Col2,0)
      + COALESCE(Col3,0)
      AS TOTAL FROM table;
```

Perhaps you could consider using 0 as default value instead of NULL if applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  In my case, null is for unspecified values, where zero is for zero values.

Answer (score 2):

**Much simpler, faster, clearer:**

```
... WHERE (col1, col2, col3) IS NOT NULL;
```

The expression returns `true` if (and only if) all fields in the [ROW expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) are `NOT NULL`. See:

- [Why is IS NOT NULL false when checking a row type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350232/why-is-is-not-null-false-when-checking-a-row-type/27353191#27353191)

Can be applied to the whole row, too:

```
SELECT ...
FROM   my_table t
WHERE  (t.*) IS NOT NULL;
```

Postgres even has a dedicated function for the purpose: [**`num_nulls()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-FUNC-TABLE). Slightly more expensive in my tests on Postgres 15, but clearer:

```
... WHERE num_nulls(col1, col2, col3) = 0;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DndCd4Kh)