# Why is IS NOT NULL false when checking a row type?

Tags: postgresql, null, row, plpgsql

I have a function `registration()`, which is supposed to add a row to a table under certain circumstances. I've included a snippet of code and output from a call.

If `select *` returns a non-empty table row (which it does according to the `RAISE NOTICE`) I want to raise the exception and not add the row. The example seems to show that `rowt` is not null, and yet `rowt IS NOT NULL` returns `f` (and the exception is not raised).

I hope this is something minor I'm not seeing.

```
select * into rowt from Email where email_email = eml;
RAISE NOTICE '%, rowt IS NOT NULL:%',rowt, rowt IS NOT NULL;
if rowt IS NOT NULL THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'email address, %, already registered.' , eml;
END IF;
```

Output:

```
NOTICE:  (7,,,), rowt IS NOT NULL:f

registration 
--------------
    21
(1 row)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Email ( 
   email_email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
   email_password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   email_id integer DEFAULT nextval('email_email_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
   email_person_id integer
);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION registration( wr text ) RETURNS integer AS $rL$
DECLARE
    eml text;
    pwd text;
    nm text;
    rle text;
    emid integer;
    rowt Email%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    eml := getWebVarValue( wr , 'email' );
    select * into rowt from Email where email_email = eml;
    RAISE NOTICE '%, rowt IS NOT NULL:%', rowt, rowt IS NOT NULL;
    IF rowt IS NOT NULL THEN
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'email address, %, already registered.' , eml;
    END IF;
    pwd := getWebVarValue( wr , 'password' );
    IF pwd IS NULL THEN
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'No password specified in registration.';
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO Email VALUES (eml,pwd) RETURNING Email.email_id INTO emid;
    --nm =  getWebVarValue( wr , 'name' );
    --rle = getWebVarValue( wr , 'role' );
    RETURN emid;
END;
$rL$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: "I want to raise the exception and not add the row" --- what about concurrent calls? What if 2 calls have passed this check simultaneously?

Comment: Can you edit your post and show the entire function and the table structure of Email? With the current information it is impossible to say what the problem is. One possible cause: rowt is a RECORD type variable and IS NOT NULL is supposed to operate on record fields.

Comment: See ["Executing a Query with a Single-row Result"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW), and the special `FOUND` variable.

Comment: @zerkms: `SET ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` is a nice safe default, and you can always turn it off on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @Kevin: Attention: `SET ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` can have negative impact on database load. It significantly increase a number of locks.

Comment: @Pavel: Postgres uses MVCC; [it does not set locks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/transaction-iso.html) (except for predicate locks, which are non-blocking and solely exist to track read/write relationships between transactions).

Comment: @Kevin: I know what Postgres uses, Serializable level was rewritten in 9.1 - Serializable Snapshot Isolation with little bit different and higher performance impact than older implementation (it has less performance impact than classic implementations, but it is not cost free or locks free).

Comment: @Pavel: Then why do the docs say `SERIALIZABLE` doesn't use locks (besides those already used by `REPEATABLE READ`)?

Comment: I am returning back to this article http://drkp.net/papers/ssi-vldb12.pdf it is named as SIREAD locks. I don't know well this technology, but I remember, so it can take lot of memory and if you don't lost performance, you have to explicitly use a READ ONLY transactions.

Comment: @Kevin: I reread PostgreSQL doc again http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/transaction-iso.html, and there is cleanly written, so this level uses locks - predicate locks.

Comment: @Pavel: Predicate locks are not like other locks and it is misleading to lump them under the general term "locks" without further qualification.  Please read the docs more thoroughly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66454/discussion-between-pavel-stehule-and-kevin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code it follows that you want to register an email address by inserting it in a table, but only if the email address isn't already registered and a password is supplied. For starters, you should change your table definition to reflect those requirements:

```
CREATE TABLE email ( 
    id        serial PRIMARY KEY,
    addr      varchar(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    passw     varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    person_id integer
);
```

The `UNIQUE` constraint on `addr` means that PG will not allow duplicate email addresses so you don't have to test for that. You should instead test for a unique violation when doing the insert.

For the function I suggest you pass in the email address and password, instead of putting the business logic inside the function. Like this the function has fewer dependencies and can be re-used in other contexts more easily (such as registering an email address via some other means via your web app). Making the function `STRICT` ensures that `pwd` is not null so that saves you another test.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION registration(eml text, pwd text) RETURNS integer AS $rL$
DECLARE
    emid integer;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO email (addr, passw) VALUES (eml, pwd) RETURNING id INTO emid;
    RETURN emid;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN unique_violation THEN
        RAISE 'Email address % already registered', eml;
        RETURN NULL;
END;
$rL$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

Answer (score 22):

#### `<row-type> IS NOT NULL`

As [@Pavel provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27352861/939860), the check `<row-type> IS NOT NULL` doesn't work like you seem to expect. It returns `TRUE` if, and only if, ***every single column*** is `NOT NULL`.

You *could* invert your test expression:

```
IF rowt IS NULL THEN
   -- do nothing
ELSE 
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'email address, %, already registered.' , eml;
END IF;
```

Any row you find contains at least one column that is `NOT NULL`, therefore `rowt IS NULL` only returns `TRUE` if nothing is found.

See:

- [IS NOT NULL test for a record does not return TRUE when variable is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765198/is-not-null-test-for-a-record-does-not-return-true-when-variable-is-set/21770324#21770324)
- [NOT NULL constraint over a set of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021102/not-null-constraint-over-a-set-of-columns/21026085#21026085)

Leaves a corner case for tables that allow all-NULL rows, though.

#### Better solutions

Test the special variable [**`FOUND`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) instead (like [@Mike commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350232/why-is-is-not-null-false-when-checking-a-row-type/27353191#comment43155325_27350232)):

```sql
PERFORM FROM email WHERE email_email = eml;

IF FOUND THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'email, %, already registered.', eml;
END IF;
```

Since we are not actually interested in the returned row, replace `SELECT` with `PERFORM` to discard the result. Either sets the special variable `FOUND` accordingly.
And the `SELECT` list (or `PERFORM` list, really) can be empty as only the existence of a row matters.

Simpler, yet, use [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS):

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM email WHERE email_email = eml) THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'email, %, already registered.', eml;
END IF;
```

See:

- [PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892233/pl-pgsql-checking-if-a-row-exists/11892796#11892796)

Answer (score 8):

Test on NULL for ROW type is specific:

```
postgres=# SELECT r, r IS NULL AS "is null", r IS NOT NULL AS "is not null" 
              FROM (VALUES(NULL,NULL),
                          (10, NULL), 
                          (10,10)) r ;
    r    | is null  | is not null 
---------+----------+--------------
 (,)     | t        | f
 (10,)   | f        | f
 (10,10) | f        | t
 (3 rows)
```

So `NOT NULL` returns true only when all fields are not null.

Answer (score 1):

You only want to test, whether the row with that email *exists*.

This can be achieved simply, with an [`EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html) sub-query expression:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM email WHERE email_email = eml) THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'email address, %, already registered.', eml;
END IF;
```

The special variable `FOUND` could work too, but it's have more value, when you want to use some fields from the found row.

In general, `<row-type> IS [ NOT ] [ DISTINCT FROM ] NULL` has special rules, and does not always inverse of each other (like [@Pavel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27352861/1499698) noted); there are 3 distinct method to test against some kind 
of unknown state:

```
SELECT r,
  r IS NULL AS "is null",
  r IS NOT NULL AS "is not null",
  r IS DISTINCT FROM NULL AS "is distinct from null"
FROM (
  VALUES
    (ROW(10::int, 10::int)),
    (ROW(10::int, NULL::int)),
    (ROW(NULL::int, NULL::int)),
    (NULL)
) AS s(r);

-- R            IS NULL     IS NOT NULL     IS DISTINCT FROM NULL
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-- '(10,10)'    'f'         't'             't'
-- '(10,)'      'f'         'f'             't'
-- '(,)'        't'         'f'             't'
-- NULL         't'         'f'             'f'
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a3d73/6)</kbd>

> [**Note:**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html) If the *expression* is row-valued, then **`IS NULL`** is true when **the row expression itself is null** or** when all the row's fields are null**, while **`IS NOT NULL`** is true when **the row expression itself is non-null** and **all the row's fields are non-null**. Because of this behavior, `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` do not always return inverse results for row-valued expressions, i.e., a row-valued expression that contains both `NULL` and non-null values will return false for both tests. **This definition conforms to the SQL standard**, and is a change from the inconsistent behavior exhibited by PostgreSQL versions prior to 8.2.

Also, there is some change in the handling of operators, when someone uses composite types, instead of row constructors:

> [**Note:**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html) The SQL specification requires row-wise comparison to return `NULL` if the result depends on comparing two `NULL` values or a `NULL` and a non-`NULL`. PostgreSQL does this only when comparing the results of two row constructors or comparing a row constructor to the output of a subquery (as in Section 9.22). In other contexts<sup>**1**</sup> where two composite-type values are compared, two `NULL` field values are considered equal, and a `NULL` is considered larger than a non-`NULL`. This is necessary in order to have consistent sorting and indexing behavior for composite types.

<sup>**1**</sup> though I could not find any query, which works that way.

Comment: **First**: you should not use `IF EXISTS (SELECT * ...` in this case when no results of the query are being used; use `PERFORM` instead. **Second**: your example looks deceptively like what Pavel Stehule posted a few hours before you, but maybe that is just me...

Comment: @Patrick not in this case, `EXISTS(PERFORM ...)` would not work, the results of the select are consumed by `EXISTS`. 2: I just wanted to highlight, why this is happening (i.e. *This definition conforms to the SQL standard*) -- mainly because there may be someone, who interested in this too (f.ex. myself: i haven't encountered this before, that's why i tested what i can).

Comment: `EXISTS(PERFORM ...` never works, but `PERFORM * ...; IF FOUND THEN ...` is *the only accepted way* ([http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT]) to test for the existence of data.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by **casting to `::text`** (**`arr[1]::text is not null`**) within an SQL select accessing some array within a composite/record type similar to this:

```
select
  arr,
  arr[1]       is not null  as nn,
  arr[1]::text              as as_txt,
  arr[1]::text is not null  as as_txt_nn
from ...  -- "...": some composite type and an array type for it must exist

row|  arr         nn    as_txt    as_txt_nn
===|  -------     ----- ------    ---------
1  |  {(1,a)}     true  (1,a)     true
2  |  {(1,NULL)}  false (1,NULL)  true
3  |  {NULL}      false <NULL>    false

-- hint: "<NULL>" is the null value representation of 
--                your sql execution environment
```

So `as_txt_nn` condition properly checks for the problem to differentiate between row 2 and 3 related to the question, if the first array composite is null or given.

The **`nn`** condition behaves (as mentioned in previous posts) in a way, that it **only returns `true`, if ALL composite columns are `not null`**.

It should work for PGPLSQL functions as well.