# Wrap PostgreSQL functions in another to conditionally combine results

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, join, plpgsql

I have a function `get_oversight(int)` that returns a single column:

```
person_id
----------
100
101
102
103
104
```

And another function `get_unfiltered_responsibility(int)` that returns the same structure:

```
person_id
----------
100
103
104
```

I need a 3rd function that evaluates and returns a subset of the above. Here's some pseudo code:

```
def function get_responsibility(person_id int):
    oversight = get_oversight(person_id)
    unfiltered_responsibility = get_responsibility(person_id)

    if number_of_records(unfiltered_responsibility) == 0:
        return oversight
    else
        return intersection(unfiltered_responsibility, oversight)
        # only ids from unfiltered_responsibility that are ALSO IN oversight
```

What would that 3rd function look like? (using v9.6)

Comment: That code is no PL/pgSQL

Comment: I described it as pseudo-code... just wanted to describe the logic I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that both functions never return duplicates. Else you'll have to define exactly how to deal with those.

In a **PL/pgSQL function** you can conveniently use the special variable [**`FOUND`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_combo_plpgsql(int)
  RETURNS TABLE(person_id int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT *
   FROM   get_oversight($1)
   JOIN   get_unfiltered_responsibility($1) USING (person_id);

   IF NOT FOUND THEN  -- !
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT * FROM get_oversight($1);
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/huwKJabv)

This **only** works on the assumption that `get_unfiltered_responsibility()` always returns a subset of `get_oversight()`, like your sample data seems to suggest. Then, if the join returns no rows, we can conclude that `get_unfiltered_responsibility()` came up empty.

Related:

- [Why is IS NOT NULL false when checking a row type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350232/why-is-is-not-null-false-when-checking-a-row-type/27353191#27353191)

Alternatively, this [**CTE**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH) wrapped in a simple **SQL function** works in any case, subset or not (can be a PL/pgSQL function too, if needed):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_combo_sql(int)
  RETURNS TABLE(person_id int)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM get_unfiltered_responsibility($1))
SELECT *
FROM   get_oversight($1) o
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM cte
   WHERE  person_id = o.person_id
   )
OR NOT EXISTS (TABLE cte)
$func$;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/huwKJabv)

Related:

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from/30276023#30276023)