# What are the semantics of "from_item is not null" / "from_item is null"?

Tags: postgresql, outer-join

Given the following query

```
select *
from jsonb_to_recordset('[{"a":1},{"a":2,"b":42}]') i(a int, b int)
where i is not null
```

I observe the result of a single row, which is the one where both columns are non-null.

When negating the where clause to be `where i is null`, I instead observe the empty result set.

I'm somewhat confused by the first version of that query not resulting in both rows, and by negating the comparison not yielding the complement of the set returned by the first query.

So far I've not been able to find the right place in the documentation where this behaviour is described, and would appreciate any pointers in the right direction to better understand what's happening.

For context, this came up for me when trying to check whether or not there was a matching row in an outer join. To avoid the above somewhat surprising behaviour, I opted to instead check for one of the non-nullable columns of the joined relation to be null/not null, which fixed my immediate problem, but makes me wonder if there's perhaps a better way to perform this kind of check that'd always work, even if all the columns of the relation you're joining are nullable, and without having to enumerate all of the columns and relying on at least one of them to be non-null.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350232/why-is-is-not-null-false-when-checking-a-row-type/27353191

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is IS NOT NULL false when checking a row type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350232/why-is-is-not-null-false-when-checking-a-row-type)

Comment: Those other two questions are very much related, and would've helped me with my original issue if I had found them then. I don't think they answer this question quite as well as the accepted answer in terms of upstream documentation and alternative solutions (like, one of them is in the context of procedural functions, and the recommendations are around using `found`, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html for row types (also known as [composite types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html)):

> If the *expression* is row-valued, then `IS NULL` is true when the row
> expression itself is null or when all the row's fields are null, while
> `IS NOT NULL` is true when the row expression itself is non-null and
> all the row's fields are non-null. Because of this behavior, `IS NULL`
> and `IS NOT NULL` do not always return inverse results for row-valued
> expressions; in particular, a row-valued expression that contains both
> null and non-null fields will return false for both tests. In some
> cases, it may be preferable to write `row IS DISTINCT FROM NULL` or
> `row IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL`, which will simply check whether the
> overall row value is null without any additional tests on the row
> fields.

You can generate yourself a cheat sheet using

```
SELECT
  x, y.a, b, y,
  y IS NULL AS "y IS NULL",
  y IS NOT NULL AS "y IS NOT NULL",
  y IS DISTINCT FROM NULL AS "y IS DISTINCT FROM NULL"
FROM (VALUES ('one'), ('two')) AS x(a)
FULL OUTER JOIN jsonb_to_recordset('[{}, {"a":"one"}, {"b": 1}, {"a":"one","b":2}]') AS y(a text, b int) USING (a)
ORDER BY num_nonnulls(y, y.a, y.b);
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/wmyWYgxn))</sup>

So for checking whether a row got matched in an outer join, you should use `IS DISTINCT FROM NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is quite obvious
for `i(a int, b int)`

`i is not null` -> `a is not null and b is not null`

`i is null` -> `a is null and b is null`

With query

```
select *
from jsonb_to_recordset('[{},{"a":1},{"b":1},{"a":2,"b":42}]') i(a int, b int)
```

output is

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| null | null |
| 1 | null |
| null | 1 |
| 2 | 42 |

and possible check's

1. NOT NULL

```
select *
from jsonb_to_recordset('[{},{"a":1},{"b":1},{"a":2,"b":42}]') i(a int, b int)
where i is not null
```

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 42 |

2. IS NULL

```
select *
from jsonb_to_recordset('[{},{"a":1},{"b":1},{"a":2,"b":42}]') i(a int, b int)
where i is null
```

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| null | null |

3.NOT (i is null)

```
select *
from jsonb_to_recordset('[{},{"a":1},{"b":1},{"a":2,"b":42}]') i(a int, b int)
 where not(i is null)
```

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| null | 1 |
| 2 | 42 |

4.NOT (i is not null)

```
select *
from jsonb_to_recordset('[{},{"a":1},{"b":1},{"a":2,"b":42}]') i(a int, b int)
 where not(i is not null)
```

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| null | null |
| 1 | null |
| null | 1 |

5.null and not null

```
select *
from jsonb_to_recordset('[{},{"a":1},{"b":1},{"a":2,"b":42}]') i(a int, b int)
 where not(i is null) and not (i is not null)
```

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| null | 1 |

6. Coalesce

```
select *
from jsonb_to_recordset('[{},{"a":1},{"b":1},{"a":2,"b":42}]') i(a int, b int)
where coalesce(a,b) is not null
```

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| null | 1 |
| 2 | 42 |

Comment: The syntax `x is null` can refer to a result set or any table as well. I never noticed this syntax before. Thank you for sharing.